# Python import failure

Tags: python, python-3.x

Got some strange import error which is as much strangely reported by interpreter.

I use CPython-3.5

Directory structure:

```
.
+-- outer
|   +-- inner
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- first.py
|   |   +-- second.py
|   +-- __init__.py
+-- main.py
```

main.py:

```
import outer.inner
print(outer.inner.var)
```

outer/__init__.py: empty

outer/inner/__init__.py:

```
import outer.inner.first
var = outer.inner.first.var
```

outer/inner/first.py:

```
import outer.inner.second
var = outer.inner.second.var
```

outer/inner/second.py:

```
var = 1337
```

then, I run `main.py` and script fails with this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import outer.inner
  File "/outer/inner/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import outer.inner.first
  File "/outer/inner/first.py", line 2, in <module>
    var = outer.inner.second.var
AttributeError: module 'outer' has no attribute 'inner'
```

So, Python does not want to bind names correctly. Although import statement in first.py: `import outer.inner.second` is executed without crashing, this statement binds to name `outer` something like an empty package, which doesn't have (but should) the module named `inner`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: So `inner` is trying to import from `outer` - why? Why doesn't `first.py`, for example, just `from .second import var`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm relatively new to Python, but I heard that relative imports are quite controversial. And anyway, I just want to find out, what the hell is doing wrong here, not only what should I do instead

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html, then [edit] to clarify the question if still needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to import relative paths, not absolute ones. I do not know what you are trying to achieve, but correct way to import something from a file on the same level is to use a dot `.` so In your `first` file use something like:

```
from .second import var as second_var
var = second_var
```

And in your `inner/__init__.py` file something like:

```
from .first import var as first_var
var = first_var
```

This allows you to avoid name conflicts as well as keep names simple, unique and generally more readible code.

EDIT:

Also if you are nw to python consider adding interpreter comment in your `main.py` module. It's convenient for users of Unix-like systems (OS X, Linux etc.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```